# How to Print numbers in sequential manner using TPL multiple tasks

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

What is the problem with the following code?

I am trying to print numbers in sequence. One Task is for printing odd numbers and the other task is for printing even numbers.

Could somebody help me how to introduce the synchronization, so that I can get sequenced numbers from 0-10?

Code :

```
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

Task.Run(() =>{

        var printNumbers = new PrintNumbers();


        for(var i =0; i<10; i++)
        {                
                if(i % 2 == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine(i);                
        }
})


Task.Run(() =>{

        var printNumbers = new PrintNumbers();

        for(var i =0; i<10; i++)
        {                
                if(i % 2 != 0)
                    Console.WriteLine(i);                
        }
    }
})



 oddTask.Start();
evenTask.Start();

Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { oddTask, evenTask});

public class PrintNumbers
{
    private static object seqNumbers = new object();    

    public void PrintOddNumber(int number)
    {
        lock(seqNumbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
    }

    public void PrintEvenNumber(int number)
    {
        lock(seqNumbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I am using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: What do you think `Wait()` does?

Comment: Wait allows the program to wait for both of the tasks to complete before the program terminates

Comment: No. Not for both. For each. And it will not wait. It will block. So your second task won't even be started before the first has completed.

Comment: You could remove all that taking and have two loops executed sequentially and it may run even a little faster and have the same output.

Comment: How would you expect two tasks to output all these numbers in sequence though? There's no way for them to coordinate here so you might get 2,4,6,1,2,3 for example.

Comment: Also, this wouldn't even compile as the delegate in `Task.Run` doesn't take a parameter.

Comment: In fact, you shouldn't be using `Wait()` at all. And on top of that, you chose a fairly bad example. If you want a list of values 1 to 10 _in ascending order_ then splitting partitions in odd and even makes your life unnecessarily hard. Why not split into 1 to 5 and 6 to 10 and then just join results?

Comment: No , please don't consider pitting it into one same task. This was the question I have been presented in programming exercise and now I want to solve the problem.

Comment: Well. Answer: you can do that but the measures needed to get to the desired output makes doing it in that particular way nonsensical. You need independent partitions.

Comment: Of course, you could create a list of odd and a list of even values and after their creation output by consuming them alternatingly. But I don't know if that's allowed as per your assignment.

Comment: I am mentioning again this fact that this was the problem I faced during one of the assessments. I cannot change this. They want to check something. Consider some other objects instead of odss and even numbers. Both threads should stay as it is and they should process stuff sequentially.

Comment: Yes. The concept is flawed. You want it sequencially? _Do_ it sequentially. It doesn"t make sense (based on the information we have) to do something in parallel, when you have a crabton of locking and synchronizing because what you do needs to be done in sequence. If you are not even allowed to work around that, then ok. They _want_ crazy, they get crazy.

Comment: What output do you expect here? Do you expect even numbers and odd numbers to be interlaced perfectly? Because if that is the case, you need to collate the numbers in each task then output then interlaced at the end, or have each task wait for the other to complete it's next number.  You need to be more specific.

Comment: @DavidG: Whatever the way, the numbers should be printed sequentially. Either both threads can do synchronization / signal or some other manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the problem with the following code?

```
object seqNumbers = new object();
Task.Run((seqNumbers) =>{   // 1. Task.Run does not allow to pass arguments
        for(var i =0; i<10; i++)
        {
            lock(seqNumbers)  // 2. Using `lock` in here is problematic : 
                              //    you cannot enforce a toggle with a single one.
            {
                if(i % 2 == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
})
.Wait(); // 3. This will block until the Task is completed

Task.Run((seqNumbers) =>{
    lock(seqNumbers)
    {
        for(var i =0; i<10; i++)
        {
            lock(seqNumbers)
            {
                if(i % 2 != 0)
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
})
.Wait();
```

So, you see: The locking here is actually futile, because both Tasks run in sequence to each other. If you want Tasks to run in parallel (potentially), you need to start both and then await both.

If you need sequential output without utilizing intermediate data storage of results, then you have to do something awkward like this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        var oddsem = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);
        var evensem = new SemaphoreSlim(0,1);
        
        await Task.WhenAll(
            Task.Run(async () => {
                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                    await oddsem.WaitAsync();
                    try{
                        if( i % 2 == 0 ) Console.WriteLine("A: {0}",i);
                    }
                    finally{evensem.Release();}
                }
            }), 
            Task.Run(async () => {
                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                    await evensem.WaitAsync();
                    try{
                        if( i % 2 == 1 ) Console.WriteLine("B: {0}",i);
                    }
                    finally{oddsem.Release();}
                }
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A: 0
B: 1
A: 2
B: 3
A: 4
B: 5
A: 6
B: 7
A: 8
B: 9
```

See [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YOo9Qs).

**Which defeats all the benefits of making this parallel in the first place.**

Comment: Thanks for piling up the answer. Let's say we, run both tasks parallelly and i am not waiting at all.  Why not implying lock will solve the problem. As lock will be released and next thread will write the number and then again lock will be acquired on the other block and so on..

Comment: Think and write code in Tasks _or_ in Threads. Never both. You cannot lock on a singular object for this scenario because you need to ensure one must wait until the other is finished and then that one must wait. Using one lock the latter thread could be picked to just run a little longer. And it could, because the lock is free. So you end up in unpredictable behavior.

Comment: See my edited code. Now I have class and I am sharing the lock. This lock is shared and static. So no matter if every time new object is constructed within the Task.Run

Comment: I already implied, it is the _same_ instance. You need two locks to enforce a toggle. That's my point. But anyway: the actual goal should be to find a solution that is completely free of locking.

Comment: But just to conclude,  if we stay within the current code ( 2-Tasks ), we would definitely need locking and the way you implied. Right?

Comment: At least similar to the way I showed. Except what you are doing is fundamentally different from just outputting a number... but given you need to enforce such a "toggling" behavior between to otherwise parallel tasks, then yes: you more or less need to do something like that. And I still would heavily encourage to look for and suggest a smarter way to get to the desired result.

Comment: BTW : Why you are not starting the tasks?  I hope we need to start the tasks as well, otherwise they are not printing anything. Do you think task is already started ? In that case, I am not getting any output.

Comment: Thanks, I got. I need to put await statement before Task.WhenAll.
One last question : Why we need to initialize odd Task as Semaphore(1,1) and evenTask as 0,1? Could you just elaborate on this?

Comment: The first digit is inital Count and the second one is Max count. When you enter the semaphore, the count is decreased by one (if it was greater than 0), on Release the count is increased. So, if you init with (1,1) you say the first Wait shall succeed but only 1 should ever succeed. If you initialize it with (0,1), you say the first Wait shall wait until signaled.